# Cannot find modules when deploying express + typescript to heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku

First, My current setup works locally. I've been stuck on this problem for days.

Second, I'll describe it by sections

- directory structure
- typescript setup (tsconfig + path mappings)
- setup related to `module-alias` package + package.json
- step how i deploy to heroku
- the error log by heroku

---

#### Directory structure

```
├── client/
│   ├── src
│   └── package.json
├── server/
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── package.json
└── shared/
    ├── helpers/validators.ts
    ├── constants/tags.ts
    └── models/bookmark.ts
```

---

#### tsconfig setup

> Note:
> I'm using path mappings/alias set in tsconfig.json. I installed the package module-alias for the compiled files to be able to find the path mappings.

On my tsconfig, i'm importing a file that is outside the typescript project where tsconfig.json is located

As you can see on the directory structure, the tsconfig.json is under **server** folder and i'm importing files from the **shared** folder

So here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["../shared/models/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["../shared/constants/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["../shared/helpers/*"]
    },
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "../",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*", "../shared/**/*"]
}
```

---

### package.json + setup related to `module alias` package

> Note: the path for _moduleAliases is based on the path of the compiled javascript file

```
{
  "name": "pocketlite-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@models": "build/shared/models",
    "@constants": "build/shared/constants",
    "@helpers": "build/shared/helpers"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod": "node build/server/index.js",
    "start:staging": "export NODE_ENV=staging && nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register index.ts",
    "start:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register index.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm i --only=dev",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "csrf": "npx http-server -c-1 -d false -o /csrf-test"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.3",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "@types/mongoose-delete": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/mozilla-readability": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/puppeteer": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/turndown": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mozilla/readability": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/csurf": "^1.9.36",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "isomorphic-dompurify": "^0.6.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.28",
    "mongoose-delete": "^0.5.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^5.2.1",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.15",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.11.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.6.1",
    "turndown": "^6.0.0",
    "turndown-plugin-gfm": "^1.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

---

#### Steps how I deploy in hero

1. heroku create pocketlite-server
2. heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
3. heroku git:remote -a pocketlite-server
4. git subtree push --prefix server heroku master

---

#### The error log in heroku

relevent npm scripts for heroku

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod": "node build/server/index.js",
    "start:staging": "export NODE_ENV=staging && nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register index.ts",
    "start:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register index.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm i --only=dev"
  }
```

Error log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.x
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.13.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.x (replacing 6.14.8)...
       npm 6.x installed
       
-----> Prebuild
       Running heroku-prebuild
       
       > pocketlite-server@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild /tmp/build_8e06db38
       > npm i --only=dev
       
       
       > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_8e06db38/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       added 194 packages from 194 contributors and audited 665 packages in 7.23s
       
       19 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > puppeteer@5.2.1 install /tmp/build_8e06db38/node_modules/puppeteer
       > node install.js
       
       
       
       > nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall /tmp/build_8e06db38/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       added 661 packages in 19.572s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > pocketlite-server@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_8e06db38
       > tsc -p .
       
       helpers/link-scraper.ts(12,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models/bookmark.model' or its corresponding type declarations.
       helpers/validators.ts(1,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@constants/patterns' or its corresponding type declarations.
       models/bookmark-favorite.ts(2,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models/bookmark-favorite.model' or its corresponding type declarations.
       models/bookmark.ts(7,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models/bookmark.model' or its corresponding type declarations.
       models/tag.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models/tag.model' or its corresponding type declarations.
       models/user.ts(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models/user.model' or its corresponding type declarations.
       routes/bookmarks.ts(4,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@constants/tags' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! pocketlite-server@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p .`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pocketlite-server@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.tNTfH/_logs/2020-10-04T01_44_27_692Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

---

**Update:**

- I have also tried to dockerize my app, and the same error still occurs.
- I've discovered that it is related to typescript not resolving path mappings to their corresponding paths without a module bundler that rewrites path like webpack (w/c i don't use currently).
  Here's the relevant [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-454256799) in typescript's github issue